# How to read head(-er)less ASCII, identify specific rows using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ascii

Doing this in Excel using VBA is straight forward, however for extended data analysis, plotting capability, R has to be used. The instrument's software only outputs .csv files and without headers. It has to be read separately for analysis.

What I am trying to do (need to do):

- Read multiple .csv without headers (4 columns). Each file can only be distinguished by name, name only.
- Pick few specific rows from each file. e.g. a row with first column
  value = 101, column value = 201 etc. Each file only has 500 rows. I sense there is a need for a looping somewhere here to read the specific row(?)
- Store above values into a data frame for all the files
- calculate some stats on it
- plot the stat results
- finally output data frame, stat analysis, plot into an Excel, .csv

I already tried how to read .csv using R, store into a data frame, perform analysis on data frame items and plot. This process flow to be repeated daily for each instrument run. I run two instruments. I want to save a code snippet that can be run each time.

The only issue I am facing, I am not sure how to locate those specific rows. The next issue is how to go about output into Excel.

.csv input file format:

```
V1, V2, V3, V4
numeric (0 decimals), numeric (with 4 decimals), alpha num, alpha num
001, 12.8975, XY03, XY05
...
485, 89.2134, XY02, XY7
```

Update 1:
Due to some changes with the instrument sw, [files are in ASCII format](https://ronaldduncan.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/text-file-formats-ascii-delimited-text-not-csv-or-tab-delimited-text/) instead of CSV. This brings much limitations. Facing issues installing `raster` package to support ASCII. Using the following instead. Installed `sqldf` package to support sql. However that gives an error.

```
> fl1 <- read.table("~/rcodes/dt07042017/fileone.ASC", sep=",") 
--read ok
> sv1 <- sqldf('select FNAME "F1", V2, V3, V4 from fl1 where V1 in (101, 201, 301)') 
Warning message: Quoted identifiers should have class SQL, use DBI::SQL() 
if the caller performs the quoting.
```

Then installed DBI package. Not sure what it does. The sql worked. This is just one file, I need to read 1000s of files, picked specific row values and saved them into one table/df. Wrote the following broken lines. It fails as I can't find a way to inject file name.

```
> df <- NULL
> fn <- NULL
> n <- 1
> for (f in files) {
+     fn <- file_path_sans_ext(f)
+     df0 <-read.table(f, sep=",")
+     n <- n + 1
+     df <- sqldf('select n, fn, V1, V2 from df0 
where V1 IN (101, 201, 301, 401)') 
-- thought R could read fn just as df0
+     df <- rbind(df) --further fn and n only reads two files
+ }
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
no such column: n, df1
```

I am not **quite happy** using sql on R. Is there any other way in R to do this without using sql packages and get above done?

## **UPDATE 3**

Instead of getting 2:20 values (18 values) in that column, **I want to get the mean of row 2 to 20. How can I do that?**

```
#set working directly to the folder where csv files are located
files <- list.files(pattern='.csv')
m = data.frame()
 for (k in 1:length(files)){
  +     csv = read.csv(files[k], header = FALSE)
  #picking up 2:20 consecutive values, value for row 50,120,150 so on
  +     data = csv[c(2:20, 50, 120, 150, 175, 200), c(1,2)]
  #-pivot transform col/row- data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  #but that line screwed up the data
  #when those selected values are with NA/blanks
        data$file = files[k]
  +     m = rbind(m, data)
 }
```

Comment: Please give an example of your csv files. As for exporting the results in Excel, there are a huge number of packages that you can use: `WriteXLS`, `xlsx` are just some of them.

Comment: How big are your files? If not so much, you could just read them all and then subset afterwards. Like `x<-read.csv(yourfile);x<-x[x[[1]]==201,]` to select only the rows where the first column is 201.

Comment: Is it possible to add a new column to identify each file data when reading into R? Data point needs that identity - to retain the knowledge to where the data correspondence. I am going to away for the next half a day. I will post the updates that I make. If you can then comment, then great.

Comment: @nicola I have updated the question. As per the update, the files have been changed to ASCII format. Due to that, there's much limitations compared to CSV. I read one file data into a table and installed the `slqdf` pkg. However not able to pass through the current bottle neck.

Comment: @nicola this doesn't cover the needs of my question. As mentioned earlier, could you suggest another way to read specific data from all files at once and adding them into a data frame with an identifier?

Comment: I don't get which part isn't covered by my answer. Please clarify. Are the files I created in my answer similar to yours? If not, in what they differ? What actually doesn't work?

Comment: @nicola our file names are dynamic. 1000s of files being saved and no intention of wasting time to type all file names into vectors daily. Why aren't you iterating through all the files at once and scooping the lines needed from each file and save it into a data frame? We can't afford to run batches. We run the experiments in one go by many, and then we want to compile all files. That's why I said your answer's process flow doesn't suit my need. There's too much of manual intervention. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Of course you don't have to "type the file names". Are the files stored in a directory? Use `list.files` to have their names and then apply my answer. I thought that the file names were a given, and I included their definition in my answer just to make it reproducible. The question wasn't about "getting file names" after all. BTW, I *am* iterating through all the files: it's the `sapply` parts. Don't get the "We can't afford to run batches" part at all. I'm making a small edit to my answer to cover what I thought was obvious regarding the file names.

Comment: @nicola Let me try yours one more time. Please bear with my approach as this aspect a bit new to me. I am trying my best to not use sql with R. In your answer you are saying `I suggest you to read them in bunches and apply the above to each bunch`, so it is a bit confusing as I have no intention to read in bunches but one go. Also added a link explaining what ASCII files are. ASCII has no direct support from R unless otherwise certain packages are added. But .csv has organic support from R without any packages (from what I encountered/read).

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, but I'm not bothering to waste much more time, sorry. There is no "reading all files in a go": of course the computer will read one at a time. But you can: read before all files and store them in memory and then process one at a time *or* you can read 50 of them and process them *before* reading the next 50 and so on till you finish. If the problem is reading the file, just provide an example (maybe a few lines of it)!

Comment: @nicola Certainly. Is there a way to output the data frame by `V1, V2, V3, FName` format? e.g. 101, 201, 301, FN1 . Pretty much transforming the tabular into more like pivot?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you mean by "ASCII files". Hope that the following is significantly similar to your problem. Say that you have the following files:

**File 1.csv**

```
101 0.8117 AFWSK QSZDP
099 0.4594 MDKKK DHVAH
301 0.8730 HMRCR PQSMB
012 0.4705 OHHZL CIKVM
012 0.1335 KKEHQ YFNJU
201 0.2967 XFIPZ PMNYT
301 0.2470 WKLIV TBHZP
101 0.9182 SSEHT QYBUW
101 0.8076 VKRSO BUGJL
301 0.5861 PICFN UFTWC
```

**File 2.csv**

```
201 0.0767 FHWLL FZKQF
301 0.3176 HDBVJ EIUNJ
301 0.9606 LHODD XRYFE
301 0.8327 NKGVT LYTUJ
012 0.8073 KOBXD GBEFA
099 0.9414 ZCOCX ENFAV
101 0.3683 UTBUG RKIQU
012 0.1515 XXJZI MEWVI
012 0.0383 IUKQQ PAIFV
301 0.2304 GKIKJ GEOZT
```

stored in a directory called `path/to/my/dir`. Say that this directory contains also other files, but you know that the ones containing data are names in the `[0-9]+.csv` format (i.e. some number, followed by `.csv`). Of course you have a big number of them and their names can be different; since the question doesn't contain any hint regarding this, I'm just providing an example, hoping that you might adapt this step to your real problem.

Now:

```
#you get the name of all files. No manual typing.
filenames<-list.files(path="path/to/my/dir",pattern="[0-9]+\\.csv",full.names=TRUE)
#reading them all
dataFiltered<-sapply(filenames,function(x) {
                    y<-read.table(x)
                    y[y[[1]] %in% c(101, 201, 301),]},simplify=FALSE)
finalRes<-cbind(do.call(rbind,dataFiltered),
           fileOrigin=rep(names(dataFiltered),vapply(dataFiltered,nrow,1L)))
```

To get something like:

```
#    V1     V2    V3    V4 fileOrigin
#1  101 0.8117 AFWSK QSZDP      1.csv
#2  301 0.8730 HMRCR PQSMB      1.csv
#3  201 0.2967 XFIPZ PMNYT      1.csv
#4  301 0.2470 WKLIV TBHZP      1.csv
#5  101 0.9182 SSEHT QYBUW      1.csv
#6  101 0.8076 VKRSO BUGJL      1.csv
#7  301 0.5861 PICFN UFTWC      1.csv
#8  201 0.0767 FHWLL FZKQF      2.csv
#9  301 0.3176 HDBVJ EIUNJ      2.csv
#10 301 0.9606 LHODD XRYFE      2.csv
#11 301 0.8327 NKGVT LYTUJ      2.csv
#12 101 0.3683 UTBUG RKIQU      2.csv
#13 301 0.2304 GKIKJ GEOZT      2.csv
```

The above should work, but could be memory expensive. If you have a big number of files, I suggest you to read them in bunches and apply the above to each bunch. This means that you don't pass all the `filenames` object to `sapply`, but you can pass a subset of it each time till you finish.

At the end, you `rbind` all the `finalRes` together.

Comment: Nice! But file names are dynamic. 1000s of files being saved and no intention of wasting time to type all file names into vectors daily. Why aren't you iterating through files?

Comment: I have been using an "improvised" version of your/other's codes to read csv files. Yes I installed the required libraries to read csv and also changed all ASC to csv files.

Comment: I am updating my question with the current version of the code. What I want is to read the mean/average of a range of data values in a column. e.g. 2:20 range. I am not sure how to do it. I tried few variations, all have failed so far.