# Reading ASCII into table and select specific rows from the table in R

Tags: r, for-loop, ascii

[This is related to the question that I posted earlier.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43290427/1389394) I believe there must be a better way to do this in R without using sql in R. Because sql fails to recognise the variables in R, it gives me some errors at the moment. This could be due to syntax errors. SQL error is obvious as those columns aren't in the df0. There needs to be a way to inject the filename into the selected rows though. Why is't R reading more than 2 files?

Anyone could point at the root cause and throw in some ideas for a better solution?

```
> df <- NULL
> fn <- NULL
> n <- 1
> for (f in files) {
+     fn <- file_path_sans_ext(f)
+     df0 <-read.table(f, sep=",")
+     n <- n + 1
+     df <- sqldf('select n, fn, V1, V2 from df0 
where V1 IN (101, 201, 301, 401)') 
-- thought R could read fn just as df0
+     df <- rbind(df) --further fn and n only reads two files out of 1000s
+ }
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
no such column: n, df1
```

Comment: Code posted to SO's r tag must be minimal complete and reproducible so that anyone else can just copy it into their session to run it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I don't quite follow you. Quite new to this tag as you can see. Is it a new convention or just for R? can you point out what exactly to be "minimal complete and reproducible"? Aren't user's/dev's code specific to their purpose in someway?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @G.Grothendieck this is good practice but usually isn't the case.  The above snippet has only few lines. And it is fairly variable based compared a lot of questions and answers out there. My question has to show the error and the code as it is for viewer to identify the issue. I am just wondering what is not minimal in this and why it can't be reproduced... Will the down vote be reverted upon question update? Further I am requesting an alternative to sql.

Answer (score 1):

`sqldf` creates a temporary database and uploads *data frames* (not scalars or other objects) from your workspace to it.  If you want to incorporate scalars then you can inject them into your SQL statement using `fn` from the gsubfn package (which the sqldf package automatically loads).  For example, using the built in `BOD` data.frame:

```
library(sqldf)

n <- nrow(BOD)
s <- "abc"

fn$sqldf("select $n as n, '$s' as string, demand from BOD")
```

giving:

```
  n string demand
1 6    abc    8.3
2 6    abc   10.3
3 6    abc   19.0
4 6    abc   16.0
5 6    abc   15.6
6 6    abc   19.8
```

Suggest you read `?sqldf` and `?fn` and go through the examples on the [sqldf github home page](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf)  since all this is well documented.

Comment: As mentioned I prefer not to use sql within R. I had my enough share of sql in the past. Plus for other users (who aren't conversant with sql and db) benefit, preference is solely on R. Can you suggest an alternative to achieve the same without using sql?

Comment: Sometimes in the face of a problem, we really don't seem to see the solutions. Now that I revisited this accidentally, I note how I had missed out your points. I found an answer without using sql library (brute force).. thanks for the direction.